# Matching special character in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr

Hi I have the following data.

```
shopping_list <- c("apples x4", "bag of flour", "bag of sugar", "milk x2", 
                   "appple+20gfree", 
                   "BELI HG MSWAT ALA +VAT T 100g BAR WR", 
                   "TOOLAIT CASSE+LSST+SSSRE 40g SAC MDC")
```

In my second step I remove all whitespace in `shopping_list`.

```
require(stringr)
shopping_list_trim <- str_replace_all(shopping_list, fixed(" "), "")
print(shopping_list_trim)
[1] "applesx4" "bagofflour" "bagofsugar"             
[4] "milkx2" "appple+20gfree" "BELIHGMSWATALA+VATT100gBARWR"
[7] "TOOLAITCASSE+LSST+SSSRE40gSACMDC"
```

If I want to extract the string that does not contain plus sign I use the following code.

```
str_extract(shopping_list_trim, "^[^+]+$")
[1] "applesx4"   "bagofflour" "bagofsugar" "milkx2"  NA  NA NA
```

Would like to help to extract the string that contain **plus sign**.
I would like the output to be the following one.

```
NA NA NA NA   "appple+20gfree" 
"BELIHGMSWATALA+VATT100gBARWR" "TOOLAITCASSE+LSST+SSSRE40gSACMDC"
```

Does anybody have idea how to extract only string that contains plus sign?

Comment: `grepl("(?=.*\\+)", shopping_list_trim, perl=T)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
> str_extract(shopping_list_trim, "^(?=.*\\+)(.+)$")
[1] NA                                
[2] NA                                
[3] NA                                
[4] NA                                
[5] "appple+20gfree"                  
[6] "BELIHGMSWATALA+VATT100gBARWR"    
[7] "TOOLAITCASSE+LSST+SSSRE40gSACMDC"
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
^(?=.*\\+) #Lookahead to check if there is one plus sign
(.+)$ #Capture the string if the above is true
```

Comment: About this part of regex  `^(?=.*\\+)`. What is the role of ?=. character?

Comment: @ssssssssssss Its a lookahead..They are of zero width means they don't consume any string..So basically we are just checking if there is a `+` sign present in string without even moving forward in string..`(?=)` is syntax of lookahead.. **[read](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**

Comment: the answer given by @ClasG is much simpler if you find it complicated to understand

Answer (score 0):

If you can't/don't want to use look-arounds, try

```
^.*\+.*$
```

It matches `anything` followed by a `+` followed by `anything` :)

[See it work here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qQ9qS2/1).

Regards